# Integration Spring boot et Spring webmvc Erreur : no autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm implementing a SOAP webservice using Spring boot mixing it with Spring WebMVC and JDBCTemplate. I have a problem using @Autowired on my DAO

**ContactDAO**

```
public interface ContactDAO {

public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);

public void delete(int contactId);

public Contact get(int contactId);

public List<Contact> list();

}
```

**ContactDAOImpl**

```
@Repository
@Controller("contactDAO")
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public ContactDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Override
public Contact get(int contactId) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact_id=" + contactId;
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Contact>() {

        @Override
        public Contact extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {
            if (rs.next()) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                contact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                contact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                contact.setAdress(rs.getString("address"));
                contact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
                return contact;
            }

            return null;
        }

    });
}
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<bean id="contactDAO" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAOImpl"/>
```

**ContactEndpoint**

```
@Endpoint
public class ContactEndpoint {
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;

@Autowired
public ContactEndpoint(ContactDAO contactDAO) {
    this.contactDAO = contactDAO;
}

@Cacheable(cacheName="imageCache",  keyGenerator=@KeyGenerator(name="StringKeyCache"))
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getContactRequest")
@RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponsePayload
public GetContactResponse getContact(@RequestPayload GetContactRequest request){
  GetContactResponse response = new GetContactResponse();
  response.setContact(contactDAO.get(request.getId()));
  return response;
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contactEndpoint' defined in file [C:\KitDev\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\gs-producing-web-service-0.1.0\WEB-INF\classes\com\spring\countries\ContactEndpoint.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO]: : No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5200) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 33 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the probleme by moving ContactEndpoint to the same package name as my DAO, since at first I had the Endpoint at com.spring.countries while the DAO was at net.codejava.spring therefor Spring could not find the binding. Moving the ContactEndpoint to net.codejava.spring solved it. Thanks fo your help

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `@Controller("contactDAO")` from your `ContactDAOImpl` class and change `@Repository` to `@Repository("contactDAO")`

Answer (score 0):

In fact seems you have 3 declarations of ContactDAOImpl `@Controller, @Repository` and the `<bean id="contactDAO" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAOImpl"/>` just use one of them, and enable `<component-scan base-packages="net.codejava.spring"/>` or using java config `@ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")` with a `@Configuration` annotated class so spring can pick them up